# I am migrating 3.2.X to 4.1.10 version of spring data Elasticsearch but SearchResultMapper class is not available to use

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am migrating 3.2.X to 4.1.10 version of spring data Elasticsearch but SearchResultMapper class is not available to use. I have searched this in documentation of spring also but no luck for alternative class.

Comment: The functions accepting a `SearchResultMapper` were removed in 4.0. What functionality do you need that is not provided by the `SearchHit` classes that are used as return values now?

Comment: Can you help me with any link or code which can help me to migrate my code? as there are lots of functions gets changed in version 4.0 l

Comment: what functionality did you need in 3.2 that you used a custom `SearchResultMapper` instead of the default mapper?